# Python mock testing: how can I substitute a function in the test case?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I'm trying to test this kind of method that alters my incoming object, but it needs to be mocked because I can't run the code in a unit test case (requires massive files that aren't in the repo).

I want to mock the function `method_to_mock` so that it sets the `file_wrapper_object.status` to whatever I want for that test case.
**Note.** `method_to_mock` doesn't return anything.

```py
def method_to_mock(file_wrapper_object):
    try:
        process(file_wrapper_object) #<—- I can't run this in a test case
        file_wrapper_object.status = "COMPLETE"
    except:
        file_wrapper_object.status = "FAILED"
```

```py
def TestProcessFileWrapperObject(self):
    file_wrapper_object = create_wrapper_object(arbitrary_data)
    method_to_mock(file_wrapper_object)
    self.assertEqual(file_wrapper_object.status, "COMPLETE")
```

How can I mock a method that doesn't return anything but alters the incoming object?

Answer (score 0):

I have created a file `prod.py` which contains your production function `method_to_mock`. To execute the test code I have insert in that file other snippets of code as you can see below:

```
# this is your production code
def method_to_mock(file_wrapper_object):
    try:
        process(file_wrapper_object) #<—- I can't run this in a test case
        file_wrapper_object.status = "COMPLETE"
    except:
        file_wrapper_object.status = "FAILED"

#+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
# the following code has been created to execute the test code
#+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
class OBJ:
    status = "PARTIAL"

def process(file_wrapper_object):
    print("real function process")

def create_wrapper_object(arbitrary_data):
    return OBJ()
```

With the previous file the test code (file `test_prod.py`) is:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
from prod import process, method_to_mock, create_wrapper_object

def func_mock_process(file_wrapper_object):
    print("new function process")

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_ProcessFileWrapperObject(self):
        file_wrapper_object = create_wrapper_object('arbitrary_data')
        with patch("prod.process") as mock_process:
            mock_process.side_effect = func_mock_process
            method_to_mock(file_wrapper_object)
            self.assertEqual(file_wrapper_object.status, "COMPLETE")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

About test code:

- `patch()` substitutes the real function `process` with `mock_process`
- `mock_process.side_effect = func_mock_process` selects the function that must be executed by the production code during the test at the place of `process`

The output of the test code execution is:

```
new function process
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s
OK
```

The output shows that:

- the function `process` has been substituted by `func_mock_process` (this is showed by the print message `new function process`
- the value of the attribute `status` is `COMPLETE`.